Do the physics in this hypothetical space world work? What about space travel?
Basically, I have a solar system containing roughly twenty planets (though I can do closer to 10/15, if necessary). They revolve around a giant star at the center of the world. Does this work? What if I also have smaller stars/moons revolving around each individual planet?
How about space travel? Is it possible for spaceships/flying battleships to travel back and forth between these planets?

What do you mean "world containing twenty planets", or a star at the centre "of the world"?  Is this a description of a solar system?  Is the universe just this solar system?  What is the actual single question being asked here?

Stars reloving around planets does not make sense, at least for anything like real-universe stars.

??? The Sun is a medium-sized star; revolving around it there are 8 full-sized planets and some 9 or 10 dwarf planets, for a total of 17 or 18. We the humans have built spacecraft which have travelled between Earth and many of these planets, so that we know for sure that it is possible.

Sounds like a wonderful and delightful world indeed!

It depends. If your world consists entirely of this solar system, then planets could be arbitrarily far apart. Are they as close as Earth and Mars are to each other on average, or as close as Mercury and Neptune? That information is critical in establishing space travel capabilities. In any case, it will "work" if you have any planets orbiting a star at all, but life definitely won't work if those planets have stars orbiting them (which isn't possible anyways; the planets would orbit the stars, not vice versa).

Try to use less ambiguous terms in your question. Your use of "world" here is unclear. Does this mean the whole setting and there is 20 planets at unspecified places in space, or are they are orbiting the same star, or are they literally contained within a planet? Try to use less ambiguous terms.

@AlexP: I was responding to: "What if I also have smaller stars/moons revolving around each individual planet?
", stars revolving around planets does not work, at least for anything like real-universe stars.

This could be a cool question. Are you asking about a solar system contained within a hollow sphere? If we're asking about this in the Real Universe there are some issues to consider, but that would be a cool question. If that's not what you're asking, then please [edit] your post to make it more clear.

@SoronelHaetir: I was not responding to you, but rather commenting on the premiss of the question.

Ah, rats. Please review my question about solar systems of solar systems over at [astronomy.se]. The fundamental problem you have is that any planet large enough for a star of any size to orbit must be a star, itself. (Orbiting mass must be smaller than the reference mass.)

@Escapeddentalpatient. Oddly enough, the OP edited his/her post an hour before you made your comment. They didn't edit it well, but they did edit it.

Of Course it Works!

We just have to set aside the prejudices of realism. As you can see from the comments, your world does not fit what we understand of the primary world, the universe we actually inhabit. In the real world, stars indeed do not orbit planets and there is no giant star in the middle of the universe. If your question is thus "can this exist in the real world given what we know of real world science", then the answer is no.

However, in a fictional world, in a science-fantasy world what you describe can indeed be quite ordinary and totally unexceptional! We simply have to devise an entirely new kind of physics to account for the observations you provided.

1. Fifteen or twenty planets orbiting a giant star. This is no problem at all. Even in our own real world solar system, we have no idea how many planets orbit the Sun. We've got nine biggish planets and probably half that in the form of minor planets. Who knows what else is out there!

2. A star at the center of the world. Cosmologically speaking, there are a number of models that have come and gone through course of human natural philosophy. First we have to consider what you mean by "world". In human terms, this can mean many things. It can mean any kind of oecumene, some sort of unified whole. Our community here is an oecumene, the "world" of worldbuilders! The Earth itself is a broader oecumene; the solar system can also be seen as a world and so indeed the entire universe.

Since it seems you're focusing on this one giant star and its subordinate family planets, stars and moons, we'll assume that "world" and "oecumene" all refer to this one system. If other, similar, systems exist, they would each be both an oecumene unto themselves and also a part of the greater world beyond.

Heliocentrism is the observed state of our world, the solar system. Therefore a giant star with things in orbit around it makes sense using this same model.

3. Moons orbiting planets.  This too is quite normal in the real world. Our Earth has her Moon which in many ways act as a double planet. Mars has a couple tiny moonlets. Jupiter and Saturn have nearly two hundred moons between them.

4. Stars orbiting planets. Thus far, your world pretty much falls within expected norms of real world physics. In our universe, stars do have a minimum size, and that size seems to be somewhere around the diameter of a large planet like Saturn or Jupiter. Stars are basically large planetary bodies, composed mostly of hydrogen whose mass is sufficiently great that gravity compresses the molecules close enough together that nuclear fusion takes place. A planet like Jupiter lacks the mass and thus no fusion takes place.

Since you have posited the existence of very small stars, we thus need some new physics. We've got several possibilities we could examine:

A. The muonium star. Muonium is an exotic atom composed of a muon and an electron. Muonium has a very low mass, about 1/9 that of hydrogen, but seems to behave somewhat like a very light kind of hydrogen. We can therefore posit a Law of Nature that allows for stable muonium to exist, and possibly other analogous, yet nearly massless, elements. These massless elements, like Mu, could thus either interact chemically with massed elements (Mu2O) or with other nearly massless elements (Mu2).

Since these atoms exist and since their real world progenitors have properties similar to larger massed particles (such as being subject to gravitation and electromagnetism), we shall therefore posit another Law of Nature that allows for these nearly massless elements to be sufficiently affected by natural forces that they become useful.

By useful we mean able to form molecules and compounds, able to be put to use in a variety of applications (alchemy, biology, chemistry, electricity, engineering, etc) as well as analogous natural applications (living and non-living creatures, stars, planetary and stellar structures, etc.).

Thus: we have a star composed of an element whose absolute mass is about 1/9 that of a star of comparable number of atoms. We can imagine this class of stars as being capable of being quite small and rather undense in nature. I think a perfect candidate for being placed in orbit around a denser and more massive planet!

B. Submassless matter. While a muonium star would be classed as an "extremely low mass star", we can also posit the existence of "submasslessness". This kind of matter is so massless that an entire universe full of it would weigh less than a single electron. It's so massless that it's weight is actually computed on the other side of naught.

This stuff is so strange that gravity has no effect on it. Wherever it exists, mostly it just dissipates into nothing. The only observable kinds of submassless matter are underhydrogen and underhelium (and that's excessively rare!). Underhydrogen is just heavy enough, at about -1 amu, to bounce off of gravitational waves as it seeks to dissipate. This rebound effect sends molecules of underhydrogen careening into one another, producing ordinary fusion, and thus ordinary star-like objects.

Visibly, such a star looks very small, very weak, very pale and a bit blotchy. Once the underhydrogen is gone, the star just disappears as the underhelium it fused into has already dissipated.

C. Cotangential worlds. Moving a little further afield, we could posit the existence of two worlds inhabiting the same space at the same time. The "normal" world of huge stars and small planets is overlain by another "smaller" world of tiny stars (and possibly infinitessimally small planets).

As the local gravities mesh and the two worlds synch with one another, we could observe independent stars from the other world interacting with and being captured by planets in this world. We might also observe one of our planets that has captured an entire star system from the other world!

Sadly, this would only be a temporary state of affairs. Eventually, just as the two worlds entered one another's space-time context, so too they must eventually part ways. Eventually at least some of the original "small world" would begin to phase out, leaving "normal world"'s observational horizon. Curiously some bits of "small world" might be left behind --- a random star, a couple forlorn planets. In the far future, what remains is just our world that has a couple planets with incongruously small stars in orbit around them!
